# Cloned Subscription: Messages lost while consuming messages

Tags: tomcat, java, jms

We have two servers with cloned subscriptions. It is observed when both subscribers are started, messages get lost while consuming from topic.
For performance test, I pile up 5000 messages on QM and only 2300 got consumed by both subscribers.
Below in TopicConnectionFactory
**HOST="hostname" PORT="port" CHAN="channel" TRAN="1" SCPHS="cipher" QMGR="QManager"  CID="PERFTEST" BSUB="" CCSUB="" CLS="1" BPUB="" BCON="" BVER="2" PVER="8" />**

Not sure, if configuration missing.

Comment: BDSUB and CCDSUB
<Resource name="jms/XCSMQTopicConnectionFactory_Ref" auth="Container" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactoryFactory"
        HOST="" PORT="" CHAN="" TRAN="1" SCPHS="" QMGR=""  CID="XCS-PERFTEST" CLS="1" BPUB="SYSTEM.BROKER.DEFAULT.STREAM" BCON="SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE" BVER="2" PVER="8" />

  <Resource name="jms/xcsInTopicTC_Ref" auth="Container" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopic" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicFactory" SCPHS="" TOP="topicname" BDSUB="SYSTEM.JMS.D.GB_CN" CCDSUB="SYSTEM.JMS.D.CC.GB_CN" />